# Power Connector for SSD in 2009 Mac Pro

Tags: ssd, mac-pro, sata

I have a Samsung 840 Pro in my 2009 Mac Pro, and due to the 2009 Mac Pro only being SATA 2 I get about half the read/write speeds. I've been doing some research and I came across a SATA 3 PCI-E card that will work in a 2009 Mac pro.

I'm going to put my SSD in my second optical bay drive and run a SATA cable up to it, but what do I do about power?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you figured this out a year ago now -
but you need a PATA -> SATA power adapter [couple of quid/bucks/shekels from Maplin's/Radio Shack etc] & run it from one of the old superdrive power-supplies you'll find ready & waiting in that bay.

[image]